# "driver cannot be resolved" - Selenium Java TestNG

Tags: java, selenium, testng

For any TestNG users out there.  Building my first test.  From the snippet below you can see I have annotated BeforeTest with the info to set up the Chrome browser. Then I annotate a Test which should launch the Chrome browser.

HOWEVER I am getting an error in line

> UName = driver.findElement(By.name("login_user"));
>   It says it ***driver cannot be resolved***.

Would appreciate help

```
public class FirstTestNGFile {
        @BeforeTest
        public void setup() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Selenium3\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        // URL for ASK
         String baseUrl = "https://BLAH BLAH / ";     
        // User and passwords
         String goodUser = "wayne";
         String goodPassword = "askTest17";
         String badUser = "foo";
         String badPassword = "badpass";     
         driver.get(baseUrl);            
        }


@Test
    public void validuserpass() {
        // ------------------------------------------------
        // Able to login with valid username and password
        // --------------------------------------------    
        // launch browser and direct it to the Base URL 
        //  Enter a valid name for username
        // Enter Text on Register Screen        
        WebElement UName;
        UName = driver.findElement(By.name("login_user"));
        UName.sendKeys(goodUser);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to make the following changes.

The reason being, `driver` is not in the scope of `validuserpass` test.

Define `WebDriver driver` at class level i.e., before the `setup` method.

```
public class FirstTestNGFile {
   WebDriver driver;

   @BeforeTest
   public void setup() {
      driver = new ChromeDriver();
      //Add the remaining statements as it is

   }

   //Add your test methods as it is


}
```