# driver can not be resolved error while WebDriver is defined outside public static void main() from different function through Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm using Selenium through Eclipse using Java. I have multiple parts of code that I want to shorten by using a function. However driver is declared in the public static void main.When I try using the following code outside of that, it says "driver can not be resolved." How can I fix this?

```
    public void TypeinField(String xpath, String value) {
    String val = value; 
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
    element.clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < val.length(); i++){
        char c = val.charAt(i);
        String s = new StringBuilder().append(c).toString();
        element.sendKeys(s);
    }       
}
```

Comment: You should share more code regarding driver initialization

Answer (score 0):

Wait I figured it out, my bad. I didn't search hard enough on stackoverflow.

According to this 
["driver cannot be resolved" - Selenium Java TestNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42793878/driver-cannot-be-resolved-selenium-java-testng)

"Define WebDriver driver at class level"
So I'm going to do that outside the public static void main.

Edit: I still need help please! 
Defining driver at the class level removes the error, but it now I can't get any commands like "find element" or "send keys" to work.

Answer (score 0):

Deban,

You are using the "driver" within a method - but you didn't passed the driver to the method to the new function.

In your new function - add parameter of driver and use it. It will work

```
public void TypeinField(String xpath, String value, WebDriver driver) {
String val = value; 
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
element.clear();

for (int i = 0; i < val.length(); i++){
    char c = val.charAt(i);
    String s = new StringBuilder().append(c).toString();
    element.sendKeys(s);
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

While you work with *Selenium* and *Eclipse* using Java and having multiple functions you need to consider a few facts as below:

- Don't declare the *WebDriver* instance i.e. *driver* within `public static void main()`. Rather declare *driver* as a **global** and **static** variable within the class so it can be accessed from all of the functions.
- While you create the functions, declare them `static`.
- Here is a effective protocol following the above mentioned logics:

  ```
  import org.openqa.selenium.By;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

  public class main_with_function {

      static WebDriver driver;
      public static void main(String[] args) {

          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
          driver = new ChromeDriver();
          driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
          print_title("q");
          driver.quit();
      }   

      public static void print_title(String value)
      {
          driver.findElement(By.name(value)).sendKeys("duvadefet");
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Global static variables are normally a bad idea.  You are blocking yourself off from ever running parallel tests in the future because you only have a single global instance of your driver object that will be overwritten every time you re-initialise it.